# regex with range decimal positive and negative number

Tags: regex, decimal

How to allow user to put negative, positive and decimal number with range with regex?

I use the `(/^[-+]?[0-9]\d{0,5}(\.\d+)?$/)` regex below it works with positive and negative number but to range decimal number for maximum number 6, it doesn't work.

how i can do that?
Exemple :
if i put the number 123456789 :
for standard formats it should be 123456
for positive number it should be +123456
for negative number it should be -123456
for decimal number it should be 12.3456 or 1.23456 or 123.456 ...

Comment: It is not clear what you mean? Can you give an example of input where it "doesn't work", and what was expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) after first digit to limit max length:

```
^[-+]?\d(?!.{7})\d{0,5}(?:\.\d+)?$
```

[See the demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oAIUJZ/1)

The lookahead `(?!.{7})` fails if there are more than six characters after it.

Comment: the regex works very well but it count dot "." like character.

Comment: @jeein How do you mean, what string does not match? Plesae give a sample that fails. This regex matches up to 6 digits with an optional dot anywhere within.

Comment: exemple when i put 6 number : 123456 it accepted it is ok but when i add dot to this patern "." like 12345.6 there are error message  "that this incorrect number" i think it count the dot like charcter, so the character is 7 in this case.

Comment: @jeein This pattern [accepts `12345.6` as valid (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/NYITIV/1). Maybe there is some other issue with your code. You'd need to share the code to have a look on it. E.g. on tio.run or some fiddle site :)

Comment: yes it is strange, now it works, i think i have some issue blocked on my code.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a nice solution. You could do something ugly with negative and positive lookahead:

```
^[+-]?((?!.*\..*\.)(?=.*\.)\d[\d.]{0,5}\d|\d{1,6})$
```

- `(?!.*\..*\.)` makes sure there are not 2 dots
- `(?=.*\.)` makes sure there is a dot (otherwise we can match 7 digits)
- `\d[\d.]{0,5}\d` makes sure the dot is not at start or end

Comment: this regex also works very well, it solved my problem. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the decimal numbers up to 6, you will not need the `$` sign.

Also, if you already use `\d`, then `[0-9]` is useless.

Your mistake is also `\d+`. You don't want to match all digits, do you? So instead of `+`, you will need a quantifier.

So this should be the regex that you want:

```
^[-+]?\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,6})?
```

See result: https://regex101.com/r/q8DOKR/1

Comment: it works for negative and positive number, but for decimal number it count only the number after dot or comma, for exemple if i put 895.123456 it accept so the total number it is 3+6 = 9, the expected behaviour is 895.123